# How to use custom TLS certificate with ingress addon in Minikube

Tags: ssl, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I followed below tutorial for replacing Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate in minikube.
Even after doing this the ingress controller still loads fake certificate.

What am i missing ? Has anyone ever gotten this to work on minikube ?

Start minikube

```
$ minikube start
```

Create TLS secret which contains custom certificate and private key

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system create secret tls mkcert --key key.pem --cert cert.pem
```

Configure ingress addon

```
$ minikube addons configure ingress

-- Enter custom cert(format is "namespace/secret"): kube-system/mkcert
✅  ingress was successfully configured
```

Enable ingress addon (disable first when already enabled)

```
$ minikube addons disable ingress
  "The 'ingress' addon is disabled

$ minikube addons enable ingress
  Verifying ingress addon...
  The 'ingress' addon is enabled
```

Verify if custom certificate was enabled

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx get deployment ingress-nginx-controller -o yaml | grep "kube-system"
- --default-ssl-certificate=kube-system/mkcert
```

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/custom_cert_ingress/